# Git Bash or Git Shell , which is better for Windows?

Tags: windows, git, github, git-shell

I'm learning about git form a video tutorial that uses git bash and i have downloaded GitHub for windows along git shell.which is better to use in windows and is there any differences in command lines between these?

Comment: Shell is more Windows styled because it uses the underlying Windows shell, Git Bash is used with Linux commands. 
I vote to close, since it all depends on personal preferences. Primarily opinion based questions are off topic on SO.

Comment: This is probably off topic due to opinionated attractions, but I feel one factual point would be portability advantages in learning to use the shell when those skills can be used in other systems where the Windows client isn't available

Comment: stack overflow doesn't really work for "which is better" questions. In order to avoid this from getting closed, you should consider rewriting it to some clearly answerable, focused question.

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to learn the git commands by heart. Go for Git Shell. If you someday switch over to a unix system, it would be much easier for you